# Excel formula as datewise transaction value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot

I have a scenario where it has three columns date ,transactions, values

| Date | transac | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19-10-2021 | IN1 | 100 |
| 19-10-2021 | IN2 | 200 |
| 19-10-2021 | off | 300 |
| 20-10-2021 | IN1 | 50 |
| 20-10-2021 | IN2 | 50 |
| 20-10-2021 | off | 100 |

I want to show them in other sheet as below can someone help

| Date | Transac | Transact | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19-10-2021 | IN | off | 600 |
| 20-10-2021 | IN | off | 200 |

The problem here is in transaction column IN1 and IN2 actually it should take as IN*.
so we need to sum of (IN*+off)

Comment: Then it should 600 (100+200+300) for date `19-10-2021`. How it is 400?

Comment: yeah it is 600 sorry @Harun24HR

Comment: The data shows no other `transac` than the ones you want to sum, so you could use SUMIF with the Date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use wild card matching for IN. Try-

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,E2,B:B,F2&"*")+SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,E2,B:B,G2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @HARUN24HR,      But how to arrange dates in E column as i have many dates and dates might varies

Comment: What is your excel version?  If you have Excel365 then could use Unique function.

Comment: If not excel365 then it's possible with formula (`INDEX(date_column, SMALL (IF(transac_column="off",ROW(date_column)),rows($1:1)))`), but simplest way is to copy the column containing the dates and to paste them where you want them, then in the DATA menu choose Remove Duplicates.